# Security benefits of hosting your CMS on localhost

Tags: web-application, php, privacy

If I host the CMS for my **online website** on **localhost**, will that mean that no one **online** can access it? If not, what is the most secure way to store your CMS?

Comment: what do you mean Host on localhost? you mean hosting a CMS on your machine? hosting a clone/ ectract of your ocaly  working CMs (a.k.a a tml dump on the server a CMS on your system) or what??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your CMS is listening to 127.0.0.1 ("localhost")** and not to any other IP addresses on your system, **then yes, no one online will be able to access it.**  You will be the only one able to access it, while logged into the computer it's running on.

It is unusual that this would be what you want, but hey, maybe you just want to use your CMS as a personal library.  If that's the case, have fun.

If your goal is to secure your CMS but still allow other people to access it, this is not an appropriate step.  If that's the case, I'd start by Googling "how to secure XXXX" where XXXX is the name of your CMS (wordpress, drupal, what-have-you).  Any major CMS will have guides describing standard security steps.

Comment: I'm using a custom CMS that I built, and I'm the only person who will be accessing it

Comment: And I think you may have misunderstood me. I will edit my question

Comment: Not sure that we're all that far apart... answer edited to clarify the only possible misunderstanding I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a server locally and putting a local Drupal/WordPress etc. CMS on that local server than sure, you could configure it not to be accessible to the outside world.

But, seeing as it sounds like you want to actually have an 'online' website that won't really work.

If you want to securely work with a CMS gowenfawr is right just lookup how to 'harden (cms name here)'. But putting it just on your computer wont really do much for you. Theoretically you could keep a localhost version of your website and then ftp it up to your host server (ftp might not be the best actually since you're looking for security). That would let you maintain control of your home server and make change there and then push to online.

But assuming you pushed the whole thing to the public server that would still leave the online cms open to potential attacks. Either way I think your best bet is to lookup how to harden your cms and connect to it securely.

As an example you wont want to login to WordPress admin through http and a public wifi connection because you could easily get your password sniffed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be secure in that other people would not be able to access it. However, if they do then you should not run this locally as your own machine could be compromised by a malicious user.

However, be aware that the following could still be possible, depending on the CMS:

- There could be an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) flaw. If the CMS is displayiing content from your online website (such as user comments), any injected script will still run if a vulnerability exists even though you are viewing on localhost. Of course, the XSS may be of limited use to the attacker, but if they know the CMS and are clever enough they could update content on your site by crafting the right script.
- The CMS will still be at risk to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) should such a vulnerability exist. If the attacker knows you are running locally and know the CMS then they could stil craft an attack.

These generally I would consider very low risk unless you have a specific threat targeting your site.

One other thing to consider is the transport mechanism from your CMS to the website. For example, any database connection. You should ensure this is encrypted and authenticated, otherwise your traffic from the CMS would be vulnerable to a Man-In-The-Middle. Check that it uses a transport that will be secure for this such as TLS.